# How Express measure time shorter than 1ms?

Tags: javascript, node.js, express, logging, time

I just have started to study Web framework called Express and I found that when webpage renderinged by Express was refreshed, Logs like below were displayed on the linux console.

```
GET / 304 20.768 ms - -
GET /stylesheets/style.css 304 0.521 ms - -
GET / 304 35.655 ms - -
GET /stylesheets/style.css 304 0.796 ms - -
GET / 304 33.824 ms - -
GET /stylesheets/style.css 304 1.023 ms - -
```

I learned that the shortest time can Javascript measure is 1ms(https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/System_time) like Date().

I had thought that logs are displayed by Express itself, so I searched every files to find words on that logs, but nothing was founded like that. I searched "304", "ms", "GET" as keyword, but nothing was founded in my project directory including node_modules.

Which file, function or module displays that logs?

Or, is anyone know how javascript count time shorter than 1ms?

I'm Sorry for my bad English.
Thank you for reading my question!

Comment: Those are GET requests to your CSS files, it looks like to me.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

The logging middleware that is most commonly used with Express is [`morgan`](https://github.com/expressjs/morgan).

Based on `morgan`'s [source code](https://github.com/expressjs/morgan/blob/939d846a703ef4e057d378319893946c9b404166/index.js#L507), we can determine that morgan gets nano-second precision time information from the underlying NodeJS [`process.hrtime()`](https://nodejs.org/api/process.html#process_process_hrtime_time) function:

```
this._startAt = process.hrtime()
```

And from the [NodeJS source code](https://github.com/nodejs/node/blob/edb3ffb0034c3d5dbaf3eacc46171801ab630d7c/src/node_process_methods.cc#L148) we get that its `process.hrtime()` gets the time information from [`libuv`](https://github.com/libuv/libuv):

```
static void Hrtime(const FunctionCallbackInfo<Value>& args) {
  uint64_t t = uv_hrtime();

  Local<ArrayBuffer> ab = args[0].As<Uint32Array>()->Buffer();
  uint32_t* fields = static_cast<uint32_t*>(ab->GetBackingStore()->Data());

  fields[0] = (t / NANOS_PER_SEC) >> 32;
  fields[1] = (t / NANOS_PER_SEC) & 0xffffffff;
  fields[2] = t % NANOS_PER_SEC;
}
```

In turn, `libuv` gets its time information directly from the underlying platform. [This](https://github.com/libuv/libuv/blob/584ba94885619d75968a7c083914fd8b75442813/src/unix/linux-core.c#L473), for example, is the Linux implementation:

```
uint64_t uv__hrtime(uv_clocktype_t type) {
  static clock_t fast_clock_id = -1;
  struct timespec t;
  clock_t clock_id;

  /* Prefer CLOCK_MONOTONIC_COARSE if available but only when it has
   * millisecond granularity or better.  CLOCK_MONOTONIC_COARSE is
   * serviced entirely from the vDSO, whereas CLOCK_MONOTONIC may
   * decide to make a costly system call.
   */
  /* TODO(bnoordhuis) Use CLOCK_MONOTONIC_COARSE for UV_CLOCK_PRECISE
   * when it has microsecond granularity or better (unlikely).
   */
  if (type == UV_CLOCK_FAST && fast_clock_id == -1) {
    if (clock_getres(CLOCK_MONOTONIC_COARSE, &t) == 0 &&
        t.tv_nsec <= 1 * 1000 * 1000) {
      fast_clock_id = CLOCK_MONOTONIC_COARSE;
    } else {
      fast_clock_id = CLOCK_MONOTONIC;
    }
  }

  clock_id = CLOCK_MONOTONIC;
  if (type == UV_CLOCK_FAST)
    clock_id = fast_clock_id;

  if (clock_gettime(clock_id, &t))
    return 0;  /* Not really possible. */

  return t.tv_sec * (uint64_t) 1e9 + t.tv_nsec;
}
```

So, in summary: nanosecond precision time is retrieved directly from the operating system, as long as the [the operating system supports it](https://github.com/thlorenz/libuv-dox/blob/master/methods.md#uv_hrtime).

Answer (score 0):

The [Performance Timing API](https://nodejs.org/api/perf_hooks.html) and [`process.hrtime()`](https://nodejs.org/api/process.html#process_process_hrtime_time) are two options in node.js.

In looking at the node.js code, it appears that the Express data probably comes from the http library [here](https://github.com/nodejs/node/blob/eac3f0adc46c3af0e94d70bb8635440382df7d7f/lib/internal/http.js#L35) and [here](https://github.com/nodejs/node/blob/d6f1e395ca74c34c3729d5089f9dbe5e41eab3da/lib/_http_server.js#L180) which appears to use `process.hrtime()`.